# how to process mutidimensional numeric array using jquery each function

Tags: php, json, jquery, multidimensional-array

below is my multi dimensional numeric array that i want to process in ajax-jquery   using each function of jquery.i am trying to process using parseJSON but in alert result always displayed undefined. So i am not encode this array to process in jquery. Any help would be appericiated. Thanks in advance.

```
Array
  (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [image_mapid] => 22
        [image_id] => 2
        [user_id] => 1228143758
        [pos_x] => 602.5333251953125
        [pos_y] => 300.3333282470703
        [image_width] => 100
        [image_height] => 100
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [image_mapid] => 25
        [image_id] => 2
        [user_id] => 1326497290
        [pos_x] => 446.5333251953125
        [pos_y] => 250.3333282470703
        [image_width] => 100
        [image_height] => 100
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [image_mapid] => 26
        [image_id] => 2
        [user_id] => 1757521573
        [pos_x] => 154
        [pos_y] => 162
        [image_width] => 204
        [image_height] => 190
    )
)

 var tag_select = '<?php echo $basepath?>Userprofile/tagselect.php';

 jQuery.ajax({  
                type: 'GET',
                url: tag_select,
                dataType:'json',
                data: 'wallid='+wid+'&userid='+<?php echo $user_id;?>,

                Success: function(data) {
                   $.each(data, function(idx, obj){
                     console.log(obj.image_mapid, obj.image_id)
                                             })
                                    }

               });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see the data is an array of objects so try

```
$.each(data, function(idx, obj){
    console.log(obj.image_mapid, obj.image_id)
})
```

Comment: what i get in console.log i assign javascript variable to console.log statement and alert but i get nothing...

Comment: hello please reply if you know anything regarding this @Arun

Comment: now i edit my question please you check my modification @Arun

Answer (score 1):

First remove the `dataType:'json'` from the AJAX and try it.

And if you provide the Json parsing source, it will be useful to find the actual problem.

Just give the Ajax like below,

```
 jQuery.ajax({  
                'type': 'GET',
                'url': tag_select,
                'data': 'wallid='+wid+'&userid='+<?php echo $user_id;?>,

                'success': function(data) {
                    // process the array here
                                    }

               });
```

Comment: i tried after remove datyTYPE: 'josn' still no success.. in alert it gave me _firebugingnore... @Akilan

Comment: removing dataType : 'json' that i already doing with my code any other update than please help me it's urgent.. @Akilan